# Remove the gap on the bottom between the logo and the menu. Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, html

How can i remove the gap between the logo and the menu. I have highlighted it with color red. Please see my website "FinancialLiteracyAdvocacy.com"

[Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WgNC.png)

Comment: Provide your code along with your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reduce header-right width to 50% like below , this will do

```
.header_right{
  width: 50%;
}
```

see img
 [image: here]

Comment: glad I could help